# Getting record where the first set of characters in attribute matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a model with a string attribute, the attribute can have values 'abc', 'def', 'ghi' or 'jkl' + count I need to get all records with the value 'jkl' + count. I was hoping something like:

```
Model.where(status[0..2]: 'jkl')
```

Would work, but it seems like it doesn't, is there a good way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use LIKE query with wildcards

```
Model.where('status LIKE ?', 'ijk%')
```

Comment: That seems like a really inefficent way of doing it since I know the target string is at the beginning

Comment: This query will just search for statuses starting with `ijk` because we have added wildcard at the end

Comment: This query will not match `vvijk` but only `ijkvv` or `ijksdd` and I think that is what you want

Comment: Guess that's the best way to do it